# Android Facebook LoginButton Callback jumps to canceled

Tags: android, facebook

I have the following code. It is a simple test of the callback function of the LoginButton in Facebook's Android API.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.e("SUCCESS", "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e("CANCEL", "Cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Facebook Exception");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The only problem is that whenever I click the loginButton, a dialog appears and disappears for a brief moment, and then the logcat prints out the "CANCEL" text. I cannot seem to fix this error, and I'm not clicking cancel, because that dialog simply shows up and immediately disappears.

Please help me fix this?

Comment: It is not printing error or success?

Comment: No, it is only printing CANCEL

Comment: is this always goes to onCancel() ?

Comment: Yes, it always goes to onCancel()

Comment: @theLonelyYak did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Facebook now requires review of applications which use publish access, you need to log into Facebook Developers Console, in Apps section select your app, click on Roles and add tester (or admin) role.
After this you should be able to get proper access token.

Comment: You save my day Gabriel :) Thank you !

Comment: can anyone please tell me the complete process

Answer (score 9):

This answer helped me in similar situation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31625256/1987045

Call `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` before attempting a sign in.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue.

It seems to be the case that if you attempt to login (using `logInWithReadPermissions` or `logInWithPublishPermissions`) when you already have an access token (with all of the required permissions) then the `onCancel` callback is executed.

That is to say you should not be logging the user in because the user is already logged in. Check for this first.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

I had the same problem. The callback was always received by `onCancel()` method.

I was performing a native login (meaning I was using Facebook App), so after talking with a work-mate, I unistalled my Facebook App to check whether a non-native loging was possible and run my app. To my surprise, before receiving the callback on the `onCancel()` method, a message informed me my **Facebook App ID** was wrong, so that was all. I had copied a wrong one instead of the one you get from https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

Now it works and even displays the permissions dialog. What I mean with this is that always try native and non-native. Maybe you get the answer from any of them.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened because I was calling `finish()` on my Activity before the Facebook callbacks could complete, causing the activity to finish with `RESULT_CANCELED` instead of `RESULT_OK`.

More specifically, my buggy code looked something like this:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mAuthRequested) {
            mAuthRequested = true;
            promptSignIn();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

What was happening is that once Facebook's auth activity finishes, `onStart()` gets called again, but `else { finish(); }` is invoked before any of Facebook's callbacks are. The fix was to remove the `else` block.

I hope this helps someone!