# Facebook Login gets cancelled

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook Log in. I have done this many times, but this problem is occurring first time. After entering email and password, log in response is "cancel" not SUCCESS. here is my code:

```
 private void prepareFblogin()
{

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    System.out.println("Success");
                    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                                        // handle error
                                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Success");
                                    }
                                }

                            }).executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("Cancel","On cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Log.d("Error",error.toString());
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

On clicking button I call this:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email","user_photos","public_profile"));
```

I have added the app on Facebook developer portal as well, iOS is working fine. For android I also have added debug hash key and keystore hash key. After logging in from app "onCancel" is called not the "onSuccess".
**I uninstalled Facebook app from the device for checking, I got "invalid App ID" error on the login dialog. The App ID shown in the dialog is not the one I am using in the manifest.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Facebook LoginButton Callback jumps to canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712111/android-facebook-loginbutton-callback-jumps-to-canceled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put Facebook App ID into strings.xml file and then set it in manifest as:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Thus dialog wont cancel.

Answer (score 1):

This almost drove me mad! And this is how it finally got solved.

In my **AndroidManifest.xml** file I removed the theme I was setting

I replaced:

```
  <activity
  android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity"
  android:theme="@style/AppLoginTheme"
  tools:replace="android:theme" />
```

With

```
<activity
  android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity" />
```

I guess my custom theme was breaking the account-kit activity somehow. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to manifest.xml this code:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
        "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

and initialize sdk facebook, just execute next method

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mContext);
```

ErmineSoft Team.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone else, but for me this happened because I was calling `finish()` on my Activity before the Facebook callbacks could complete, causing the activity to finish with `RESULT_CANCELED` instead of `RESULT_OK`.