# FacebookCallback#onCancel() is calling after login once in Facebook Sdk 4.2.0 in Android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have successfully implemented login with facebook in android app.
But now, Amazingly, When I do login one with facebook and if I try to login with facebook using facebook library 4.2.0 its onCancel() method is calling.
Help!

Comment: post some code & stack trace (if it is crashing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by calling: `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` just before trying to login.

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried the above mentioned code but the thing worked for me is 
i have written some code in on cancel same as in success

```
@Override
        public void onCancel() {
            AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            if (token != null) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        token,
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                FBObject = response.getJSONObject();

                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }
```