# Android Facebook Login Error with non-tester Facebook Account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on an Android app that uses Facebook login in order to
simply retrieve the user's facebook Profile name and ID.

Since 2 months, I was testing my app in `debug` mode, with a debug keyhash.
All the profiles I was testing my app with, were added as "testers", on my app's Facebook Developper Console. Everything worked perfectly.

Now, the app is ready. I generated a valid release keyhash, removed the all the "app tester" accounts from the Facebook App Developper Console.
Also, I switched the app to "public", so everyone should access it.

When I try to login with someone's account, in debug or release mode, it always fail. In debug mode, no log error is printed, so it's not a "keyhash" thing.

When I press the button, it opens the Facebook app, shows a progress bar, and then immediatly closes. It calls the `onCancel()` within the `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()`.

As someone else said in another stackoverflow post [login jumps to onCancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712111/android-facebook-loginbutton-callback-jumps-to-canceled), I tried so call `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` before attempting to Login.
In this case, the `onCancel()` function is not called, and the `onSuccess()` function is called. But then, if I try to execute the `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` function (as I did before when the app worked), it throws an exception (e.getMessage() is empty).

Help will be really appreciated !

**EDIT:** `Log.d("Token", loginResult.getAccessToken() + "");` prints

```
E/Token﹕ {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile]}
```

Comment: what permissions are you asking for (Facebook permissions)

Comment: The most basic permissions. I am doing :       `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, Arrays.asList("user_status"));`

Comment: When I try to login with my own Facebook account, as I am the app owner, it works. Access token is by the way still set to ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED.. But it works. But with another account, it fails

Comment: Can you briefly explain how you get your keyhash? Very briefly, I think you may have done it wrong. I had this exact issue once before...

Comment: Hmm, to be sure I get the right keyhash, my app is popping a AlertDialog, which logs the current KeyHash. It is the same as the one I entered on the Facebook Console...

I used the keytool command to get out the Hash from my generated .jks store file...

Comment: Something along the lines of keytool -exportcert -alias something something OpenSSL?

Comment: Yep !
It's working now ! That was because of the permissions I was aksing for. I replaced "user_status" by "public" profile. 
Now I have another error: if the user hasn't authorized the app, il will fail the first time, and the second call and every next calls will work. Any idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99257/discussion-between-maltesefalcon-and-apmartin1991).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of that bug was that I was asking for the wrong permissions.
I replaced `user_status` by `public_profile` in the `logInWithReadPermissions()`function.

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it (y)

Comment: Yep, thanks for made me think of the permissions thing.

Comment: No worries, just be sure to mark your answer as correct as it may help someone else in the future.